# Open-loop gain vs supply voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth

I have a question regarding the relationship between open-loop-gain and supply voltage. Using op270 as an example:

We need to operate this device at +-5V.  The datasheet has a plot (Figure 19) which shows Open-Loop-gain (in units of V/mA??) which decreases linearly as the supply voltage drops (from around 3000 at +-18V to 100 at +-5V).  Is this in any way related to the GBP of the device? I'm confused by the V/mA units here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo- it should be V/mV.

See the typical and minimum gains Avo for the different suffixes in the tables.